# How to check If a file isn't exists in folder and subfolders using python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory, subdirectory

I try to find folders that missing file name "kavi*" inside them. All the folders spread in one big folder that divided to a lot of sub folders and sub sub folders. 
I started the code like that but i don't know how to proceed:

```
import arcpy,fnmatch,os

rootPath = r"D:\PROJECTS\road57\gis\layers\taba\taba-mmi"
pattern = 'kavi*.shp'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        print(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

The out put is:

```
D:\PROJECTS\road57\gis\layers\taba\taba-mmi\8233\4022502\kavim kchulim.shp
D:\PROJECTS\road57\gis\layers\taba\taba-mmi\8233\4022950\kavim kchulim.shp
D:\PROJECTS\road57\gis\layers\taba\taba-mmi\8233\4050004\kavim_kchulim.shp
D:\PROJECTS\road57\gis\layers\taba\taba-mmi\9887\4050012\kavim_kchulim.shp
D:\PROJECTS\road57\gis\layers\taba\taba-mmi\9889\4050025\kavim_kchulim.shp
D:\PROJECTS\road57\gis\layers\taba\taba-mmi\9900\4050040\kavim_kchulim.shp

>>>
```

this print all the folders with "kavi*" file. But i need output with all the folders that don't include "kavi*" file

Comment: So what is the output you are looking for then? You are already printing all matching files.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood. Let's say that you have: `a/`, `a/b/` `a/c/`, `a/c/kavi.shp`, `a/c/d/`. What is the expected output?

Comment: for example, if i have in all folders "kavi*.shp" file and in one folder i don't have this file, i will get an output like that: missing file in D:\PROJECTS\road57\gis\layers\taba\taba-mmi\7333\4022000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `os.walk()` returns the current path as `root` and, when it is a directory, the files in it as `files`.  If none of the `files` match your pattern, you should print out the current `root`.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    if files != [] and fnmatch.filter(files, pattern) == []:
        print root
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
import arcpy,fnmatch,os

rootPath = r"D:\PROJECTS\road57\gis\layers\taba\taba-mmi"
pattern = 'kavi*.shp'
match_set = set()
non_match_set = set()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    # Return the subset of the list of names that match pattern.
    # if match doesn't occur return list will be empty, 
    # hence code goes in else block
    if fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        match_set.add(root)
    else: 
        non_match_set.add(root)    

print non_match_set
```